# IIS 7.5 not taking notice of customErrors for 404 returned by MVC 3 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5, custom-errors

I'm running my MVC 3 app (recently updated from 2) on IIS 7.5 (Win 7 64bit) with a .NET 4.0 integrated pipeline app pool and have the following set-up in web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Problem/Oops" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Problem/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

If an action method on a controller throws an exception the server and hence generates a 500 errorcode it correctly sends the browser to the default redirect URL.

However if my action deliberately returns a HttpNotFoundResult via HttpNotFound() I get the IIS 7.5 404.0 error page and not the one indicated in my web.config.

If I enter a URL that doesn't exist on my app like http://localhost/MyApp/FOO then I do get shown the page as indicated by the web.config.

Anybody have any ideas why I'm not getting redirected to my custom 404 error page when using HttpNotFound()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try below syntax instead of calling **HttpNotFound** and let me know the result ;)

```
throw new HttpException(404, "NotFound");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;`?

(see http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-04-13/asp_net-prevent-iis_75_overriding-custom-error-page-iis-default-error-page)

Comment: Ooh sounds promising. I will give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. The code in my ProblemsController never gets touched. IIS seems to be ignoring the settings or I'm misinterpreting the use of the MVC3 HttpNotFound() method.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it was the most helpful and might work for others even if it didn't work for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Matin Habibi's suggestion below did.